# Android hashtags implementation

Tags: android, hashtag

I've been looking a lot for a decent example or tutorial for how to implement hashtags in Android and I couldn't find anything, probably because it's iPhone oriented mechanism, i still need to know how to do it.

I have a `TextView`, and I want that when a user types # or @, the following will happen:

for # - all the characters after the # will be inside a
bubble that will be created after the user press on space.

for @ - an autocomplete search text box will open as a drop down list(`LinearLayout`) for the search results.

Since I'm a new user I can't add snapshots here.

Comment: https://plus.google.com/u/0/113735310430199015092/posts/WUd7GrfZfiZ

Comment: This is not a system based thing, you need to do it by yourself. You can customize however you wish. Have look the link @CommonsWare refered...